# Reduce size of snowflake-connector-python[pandas] module

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, python-3.9, snowflake-connector

I am trying to create a lambda function in AWS which connects to a Snowflake database. For this I need the `snowflake-connector-python[pandas]` package (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-pandas.html), which together with all of its dependencies has a size of over 250 MB uncompressed (around 280 MB). This is an issue because AWS lambda allows a maximum of 250 MB of dependencies (using AWS layers).

The size of the package is quite surprising, looking at the dependencies the biggest offenders are pyarrow (around 80 MB), pandas (around 60 MB), and numpy (around 40 MB). Is there a way to reduce the size of the whole package, installing only the relevant parts, so as to reduce the size to below 250 MB? Namely I need to be able to connect, read, and write to Snowflake, nothing fancy.

I know that there are other options in these cases, such as containers, however I would like to avoid this if possible.

Comment: What about using [SnowSQL command line client](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql.html)? I know it's not a python solution, but you could interact with it through a python script.

Comment: @Maxim Can you give an example of how to use this in lambda?

Answer (score 1):

I was waiting to see if any answers were posted on this very interesting problem, since I have also encountered it.

As far as I know, there is no way around this, apart from, obviously, using containers, or another method !

Comment: There is no way around layers yes but there is a trick which works, I've posted it in another answer.

Comment: That’s a nice trick (+1 btw!). And [here  it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71248868/reduce-size-of-snowflake-connector-pythonpandas-module/77865597#77865597) (to help others find it in future.)

Answer (score 1):

If your deployment package is larger than 50 MB, upload your function code and dependencies to an Amazon S3 bucket.

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-package.html[AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-package.html%5BAWS) documentation][1]

Comment: How do I call my code then? Without putting it in a container which I do not want.

Answer (score 1):

In the end what I ended up doing was uploading the whole package to the lambda ephemeral storage (located in `/tmp`), which comes with each lambda for free with 512 MB of storage. This allowed me to to use lambda with my required package without need for containers or layers, by adding this path to `sys.path` and then loaded the module from there.

Ever since I uploaded the packages to the storage I have not needed to re-upload it again so it seems to be quite permanent, at least for me. Also, there is an option to increase this size further (not sure if for free).

Answer (score 0):

Do you explicitly need Pandas?

If not try `snowflake-connector-python[secure-local-storage]`

Comment: I need the specific package I posted yes.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake Python connector version 3.5.0 has a less package size according to its release note at https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/clients-drivers/python-connector-2023#version-3-5-0-november-13-2023.

Comment: I have not checked this but it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Use layers and package each of these into its own layer.

You can have up to 5 layers

Snowflake Connector 2.1.2 (or higher) for Python.

PyArrow library version 3.0.x.

pandas 0.25.2 (or higher). Earlier versions might work, but have not been tested.

Comment: That's not going to work, all the layers which you glue to a lambda must not surpass 250 MB as a whole.

Comment: @Vandalism I recommend looking at the documentation for tools next time you share a recommendation, since the original poster already mentioned the size limit of Lambda packages (including layers).